# How does Django creates tables(sqlite)?

Tags: python, django

I am looking at this example
[django-multiple-users](https://github.com/sibtc/django-multiple-user-types-example)

When I go to sqlite shell

```
sqlite> .tables 
auth_group                       classroom_subject              
auth_group_permissions           classroom_takenquiz            
auth_permission                  classroom_user                 
classroom_answer                 classroom_user_groups          
classroom_question               classroom_user_user_permissions
classroom_quiz                   django_content_type            
classroom_student                django_migrations              
classroom_student_interests      django_session                 
classroom_studentanswer
```

There are 8 classess in models.py

```
class User(AbstractUser):
 is_student = models.BooleanField(default=False)
 is_teacher = models.BooleanField(default=False)

class Subject(models.Model):
class Quiz(models.Model):
class Question(models.Model):
class Answer(models.Model):
class Student(models.Model):
class TakenQuiz(models.Model):
class StudentAnswer(models.Model):
```

Forms.py(shown in github link above) has couple of forms.

Do forms also create tables?
Where do classroom_user_user_permissions come from?

Comment: No, `Form`s have essentially *nothing* to do with models. A form is only a convenient way to ask input from users. A form does not per se maps to one (or more) models.

Comment: The extra tables originate from many-to-many relations, and from some default apps that ship with Django (for example for authentication).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Do forms also create tables?

**No**, forms are used to ask input from a user. They can be "embedded" in a template, and can easily be used to for example decode the response into objects. Some of the forms directly indeed store the (updated) values in a model instance.

But a form can work for no model at all, one model, or multiple models at once. Furthermore once the form is gone, the data it carried is gone too (unless it is of course stored in a model, or in a file, or another persistent sturcture).

> Where do classroom_user_user_permissions come from?

This is because you probably defined a **`ManyToManyField`** between a `User` and `Userpermission`s. So not all tables directly map on models. Some relations require extra tables, since these can not directly be stored in one of the two tables.

Comment: Fantastic answer.Just one question,the User Class inherits from Abstract User,does this imply manytomany field?

Comment: @RichardRublev: no, since an `AbstractUser` is an abstract model. It therefore has no table. But in case an `AbstractUser` defines a many-to-many relation, that one will indeed be inherited, and materialized at the non-abstract models.